# Can highcharts create charts like this?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

It's very similar to polar chart with `column` type, like [this one](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/polar-chart):

[image]

But the `column` type polar chart has gaps between each axis.

Is there any way to remove that gaps and keep the strokes just like the above image?

Update:

1. How do I add labels to the chart (Just like the "NNE, NE, ENE" in the Wind rose example?
2. How do I make the y-axis lines curve instead of straight? (below is my highcharts generated chart, it's straight lines)
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a chart is possible to achieve in Highcharts.

To remove gaps you can use `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` properties. To make the ticks between points you need to set `pointPlacement: 'between'`. And to make the ticks appear above the points, you need to set a larger `gridZIndex`:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    polar: true
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridZIndex: 4,
    gridLineColor: 'black',
    gridLineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: 'black',
    lineWidth: 2,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridZIndex: 4,
    gridLineColor: 'black',
    gridLineWidth: 2,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      colorByPoint: true,
      pointPlacement: 'between'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [3, 5, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dsqhno8m/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPadding 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridZIndex